# SonarQube Web API show 0% duplication at project level although there are some at file level

Tags: sonarqube

I am using SonarQube (Version 6.7.2 (build 37468)) Web API to retrieve the duplication amount on my projects.
  But there is a strange behavior : when asking

```
http://10.117.72.197:9000/api/duplications/show?key=com.my.project:my-project
```

I get

```
{"duplications":[],"files":{}}
```

When asking

```
http://server:9000/api/duplications/show?key=com.my.project:my-project:src%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Fcom%2Fmy%2Fproject%2FMyFile.java
```

I get

```
{"duplications":[{"blocks":[{"from":489,"size":16,"_ref":"1"},{"from":520,"size":14,"_ref":"1"}]}],"files":{"1":{"key":"...","name":"...","uuid":"...","project":"...","projectUuid":"...","projectName":"...","subProject":"...","subProjectUuid":"...","subProjectName":"..."}}}
```

How can I get the global results without having to call the API on each and every file of my project ?

Thanks !